# A Python class inheriting from 'list' has items in it, but does not see that

Tags: python, list, class, inheritance

I have such a class structure:

**list** *--(parent)-->* **ClipList** *--(parent)-->* **VolumeList**

ClipList can only store Clip objects, and VolumeList - only Volume objects. This works (i. e. methods inherited from ClipList work for VolumeList) as Volume class inherits from the Clip class. So, what I try to achieve with the Volume and VolumeList classes is to get a flavour of Clip and ClipList different enough from the original to have its own class.

The problem arises when I try to make a call of a Volume object from a VolumeList. To find the place of a called clip, I run a binary search (as the list is ordered). The search is a simple binary search, and taken out of the context works, so I don't think it is worth posting the code here. The problematic bit is this conditional:

```
if ( self == [] ):
        return None
```

Now, the binary search is implemented in the *ClipList* class, and is *only inherited* by the VolumeList. The above conditional did not cause any problems when working with ClipList, but when ran with (an already populated) VolumeList, the condition

```
self == []
```

is, for some reason, actually `True`. Thus, the binary search always returns None, and I can't access any Volume objects in the list by their name (by which they are ordered), they are only accessible by their index.

Now, the populated VolumeList looks like this (though much larger):

```
[<__main__.Volume instance at 0xb6f3b1ac>, <__main__.Volume instance at 0xb6f3b24c>]
```

Also worth mentioning is the fact that ClipList is in a different module from VolumeList - this might have a role, but I am unsure.

I could post more code if needed, but I sense that the problem (and the solution) lies in the bits above; other code seems to work if tested separately from the above bits.

Where could the problem lie, why is the condition `True`?

Here is the code:

1. `ClipList.findIndex`:

   ```
   def findIndex(self, clip, start = 0, end = None, pos = 0):

       # Finds the index of the place where the given clip should be added.
       # It does that by looking at the *tapes* of the clips, and finds
       # a place where the *tape* of the clip could be inserted without
       # distorting the order. It then looks at clip's timecode to put it
       # in the right place according to the timecode. The 'pos' parameter
       # carries the information about the index which we will return.

       # Define the right end place if none is specified
       if ( end == None ):
           end = len(self) - 1

       # But first of all, check if there is a need to find the place of the
       # clip - i. e. if the list isn't empty.
       if ( not self ):
           return None

       # The second check that we have to make - whether it isn't the case
       # that we have already found what we need, i. e. the closest element
       # in the list to the clip we search.
       if ( start > end ):
           return pos

       # Now, we can implement the actual search. To do that,
       # we use the binary search algorithm.
       middle = (start + end) / 2
       currTape = Clip.physicalTape( self[middle].VOLUME )
       goalTape = Clip.physicalTape( clip.VOLUME )

       if ( currTape > goalTape ):
           return self.findIndex(clip, start, middle -1, middle )

       if ( currTape < goalTape ):
           return self.findIndex(clip, middle + 1, end, middle + 1)

       if ( currTape == goalTape ):

           currTimecode = self[middle].IN
           goalTimecode = clip.IN

           if ( currTimecode > goalTimecode ):
               return self.findIndex(clip, start, middle - 1, middle )

           if ( currTimecode < goalTimecode ):
               return self.findIndex(clip, middle + 1, end, middle + 1)
   ```
2. `VolumeList.__getitem__`:

   ```
   def __getitem__(self, key):
       # Is called whenever someone tries to get an item of the list
       # by calling 'volumes[ some_text_or_number ]'. VolumeList
       # will act as a normal list in all occassions except where the
       # key is a string. There, it will search for a volume label or
       # a tape number.

       if ( isinstance( key, basestring ) ):

           # Before checking whether the argument is a volume 
           # number, try to find if the user hasn't made an inquiry
           # about a tape. Tapes can only be called by calls such as
           # 'volumes[ "HD00345" ]', and *not* any other calls.
           if ( len(key) == 7 and key[:2].upper() == 'HD' 
                              and key[2:].isdigit() ):

               # Try to find the start and end of the sequence of 
               # volumes from the tape. To do this, search for an
               # 'infinitely small' and 'infinitely big' volumes from
               # the tape.
               start = self.findIndex( Volume( key.upper() + 'A', inFrame = -1 ) )
               end   = self.findIndex( Volume( key.upper() + 'Z', inFrame = 9999999 ) )

               if ( start != None and end != None ):
                   return self[start:end]
               else:
                   raise KeyError( 'The tape is not represented in this VolumeList!' )

           # Otherwise, assume that the user has called a particular
           # volume.
           volume = Volume.volumeLabel( key )

           if ( volume != None ):
               index = self.findIndex( Volume( volume, inFrame = -1 ) )

               if ( index < len( self ) and index != None ):

                   if ( self[ index ].LABEL == volume ):
                       return list.__getitem__(self, index)
                   else:
                       print 'The volume is here but not exactly'
                       raise KeyError( 'The volume is not in the list!' )
               else:
                   raise KeyError( 'The volume is not in the list!' )
           else:
               raise KeyError( 'Tried to call a volume by an invalid volume label!' )

       else:
           return list.__getitem__(self, key)
   ```

Comment: Do you implement `__eq__` in your custom class? And why not use `if not self:` instead? Note: the parenthesis in your condition are entirely redundant.

Comment: The problem does *not* lie in what you posted here, we'll need to see code.

Comment: I have posted the code of the two functions that are involved in the actions that lead to errors above. Now, before looking at the code, you should know that it does not work exactly as it should right now: you could notice that the __getitem__ method *does not* actually return the required volume, it returns the first volume from the tape where the searched volume lies. I'm aware of this, and this is not a mistake; so just ignore that.

Comment: Use `if end is None`; identity instead of equality testing.

Comment: `__getitem__` is *not* consulted when testing `self == []`, so the problem cannot lie there. Did you try and insert some debug statements to verify your assumptions are correct? Preferably, did you try to use `pdb` to step through the code to see what your objects contain at these points?

Comment: There is no need to insert 'EDIT' markers; we all have access to the edit history and can see here on the post when the question was last edited.

Comment: Problem solved, and yes, it had nothing to do with the `self == []` statement. The `ClipList.findIndex` method would return `None` because there was one condition which wasn't sorted out.